# How do I mark points in Audacity?

Tags: audacity

I have a long recording which I want to mark all the sound motifs for later reference.

How do I mark points while playing back so that I can jump between them (or find them easily) later?

Answer (score 3):

Add a label track, and find the start of each leitmotif. Place your cursor at the beginning of the area you want, and press ctrl+alt+v or Edit>Paste Text To New Label. This will create a new label, and if there is any text in your clipboard it will be added. However, this must be saved as a .aup (audacity project), since labels serve no purpose to audio players, and increase load time and storage space, all other formats will strip away worthless data.

Comment: You missed the point about "while playing back"  but your answer led me to the real answer which is "Ctrl+M".  You can press it repeatedly and it creates empty labels in the label track. :-)